# How do I replace vowels for another value?(a to e, e to i, etc.)

Tags: python-3.x

I need to be able to have a user input a string, and my code is supposed to look at the string and change the vowels. So all the a's become e's, all the e's become i's, and so on. This is what I have, but I don't know how to make it work correctly.

```
def askForString():
    userString=str(input("Enter a string: "))
    userString=userString.lower()
    return userString

def changeVowels(theString,vowels):
    newString=[]
    #newVowels=['e','i','o','u','a']
    for i in range(len(theString)):
        if theString[i] in vowels:
            i+=newString
        newString.append(i)
    return newString

def main():
    theString=askForString()
    vowels=["a","e","i","o","u"]
    NewString=changeVowels(theString,vowels)
    print(NewString)

main()
```

I think I need to somehow have the vowels change into new vowels, but I cannot figure out how. That's why I have it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `i+=newString` is erraneous. 
`i` is an integer while `newString` is a list. You cannot add an integer to a list.

From the question I gather that you need to replace the vowels in your string as follows:

```
a -> e
e -> i
i -> o
o -> u
u -> a
```

You have multiple ways to achieve that:

#### Method 1:

```
inputString = input() # input returns string by default, no need to call with with str()

outputString = ""
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

for character in inputString:
    if character in vowels:
        vowelIndex = vowels.index(character) # get the index of the vowel
        if vowelIndex == len(vowels)-1: # if its 'u', then we need to cycle back to 'a'
            vowelIndex = 0
        else:
            vowelIndex += 1 # if its not 'u', then just add 1 to go to next index which gives us the next vowel
        outputString += vowels[vowelIndex] # put that character into the outputString
    else:
        outputString += character  # if not vowel, then just put that character into the string.

print(outputString)
```

#### Method 2: Using dictionary to directly map the vowel to next vowel

```
vowels = {
    "a" : "e",
    "e" : "i",
    "i" : "o",
    "o" : "u",
    "u" : "a"
}

inputString = input()
outputString = ""

for character in inputString:
    if character in vowels: # checks the a key named "character" exists in the dictionary "vowels
        outputString += vowels[character]
    else:
        outputString += character

print(outputString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def changeVowels(theString, vowels):
    newString=[]
    repls = dict(zip(vowels, vowels[1:]+[vowels[0]]))
    for theLetter in theString:
        if theLetter in vowels:
            theLetter = repls[theLetter]
        newString.append(theLetter)
    return newString
```